# Stored Procedure has too many arguments

Tags: stored-procedures

Here is the code for my stored procedure, lots of things going on and lots of parameters being passed. I'm knew to sql and I'm sure there's a far better way of performing these functions but need some help! Thanks in advance! :)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCompleteRepair]

@unit_id INT,
@BasicHB NVARCHAR,
@AdvHB NVARCHAR,
@CCRepair BIT,
@CCReplace BIT,
@Fan NVARCHAR,
@RE BIT,
@notes NVARCHAR,
@bin_num NVARCHAR,
@loc_num NVARCHAR,
@repairserial NVARCHAR

AS

BEGIN

INSERT INTO RepairDetails
    (unit_id, BasicHB, AdvHB, CCRepair, CCReplace, Fan, RE, notes, completion_date)
VALUES
    (@unit_id, @BasicHB, @AdvHB, @CCRepair, @CCReplace, @Fan, @RE, @notes, GETDATE())


UPDATE Units
SET bin_num=@bin_num, loc_num=@loc_num, repair_serial=@repairserial, unit_status=1
WHERE unit_id=@unit_id


UPDATE OutBins 
SET filled=1
WHERE bin_num=@bin_num AND loc_num=@loc_num


UPDATE Orders
SET Orders.order_status = 1
FROM Orders 
--check to see if there are units for the order
WHERE EXISTS (  
        SELECT *
        FROM Units
        WHERE Units.order_id = Orders.order_id
        )
--make sure there are NO units that are not status = 1
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM Units
        WHERE Units.order_id = Orders.order_id
            AND Units.unit_status <> 1)


END


CODE TO CALL PROCEDURE:

 using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("spCompleteRepair", connection))
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@order_id", txtorder_id.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unit_id", txtunit_id.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BasicHB", ddlBasicHB.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdvHB", ddlAdvHB.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CCRepair", ddlCCRepair.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CCReplace", ddlCCReplace.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fan", ddlFan.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RE", ddlRE.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@notes", txtNotes.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@repairserial", txtRepairSerial.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bin_num", ddl_binnum.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@loc_num", ddl_locnum.Text);                   
                    command.Connection.Open();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
```

Comment: How are you invoking the stored procedure?  Can you update your question to include the actual call to it?

Comment: Also, you should explicitly specify lengths for your stored procedure parameters.  The default length is 1 for varchar/nvarchar data types.

Comment: Why are you specifying `@order_id` as the first parameter?  I don't see that parameter being used in the stored procedure.

Comment: Ah, yes. That could be my issue? I think I originally put it in because I thought I would need it for the UPDATE Orders procedure. I'll remove it from the code. Thanks!

Comment: After removing the unnecessary parameter it is working without error!! Thank you so much for your help! :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C# code you are using to invoke the stored procedure is passing in `@order_id` as the first parameter.  That parameter is not referenced in the actual stored procedure.  Try removing that parameter from the C# code.